# Why does ChromeDriver 2.31 fail to start when run in Docker?

Tags: selenium, docker

I have a Docker container based on `ubuntu:xenial`. When I try to run `selenium` with the `Chrome` webdriver loads endlessly

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
>>> chrome_options = Options()
>>> chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
>>> path_to_chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 229, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Linux 4.10.0-32-generic x86_64)
```

### Steps so far

#### Fix crash

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

When I tried to find the version of the chromedriver

```
chromedriver --version
```

I got the error that the shared library libnss3 was not found. After installing [libnss3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libnss3), it worked.

So the line

```
RUN apt-get install libnss3
```

should be added to the Dockerfile.

#### Fix 'chrome binary not found'

Install Chrome. It is not enough to install the `chromedriver_installer` via pip.

```
RUN apt-get install wget
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install
```

Comment: Working solution. After this install I had AttributeError: __ exit __. So I had to change "with" statement by driver.quit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create custom images, when standard images are already available. You should be using `selenium/chrome-standalone`

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrom
```

Then in your code launch a RemoteWebdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

Comment: Interesting solution! I know of this image, but I am already using one because this is a bigger application. But putting it in another container is an option I should have thought of. (By the way, I switched to PhantomJS - which works fine)

Comment: @MartinThoma, PhantomJS can work but it is not compatible with all types of websites and sometimes you end up spending too much time figuring out why it doesn't work. That's why I prefer chrome, but if it works for all your test/work initially then nothing to worry about